# How to do debugging in odoo on browser

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

How to debug in "Odoo" special in browses like Chrome and Firefox???

Would anybody provide information, it will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For that, you have to just start you developer mode and from there debug mode will appear on your Odoo

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear to me, but if you want to enter the built-in odoo debug mode you need to add `?debug` to the URL, right after `/web`. For example `http://odoo.your-site.com/web?debug`.

When in this special mode you get a debug menu, with various technical options:

[image: debugging menu in odoo]

Also, when you are in debug mode odoo doesn't minify the JS files, allowing you to use built-in browser JavaScript debug tools more easily.

Comment: Tranmmer thanks for your valuable reply, but i want in detail, what rpc call request and response, how to debug step by steps, see value of particular field value

Comment: FYI, on newer versions of Odoo, the debug on *with assets* won't minify the JS/CSS, debug ON but without assets still minify them.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the console in browser(using F12 key). It will display each request and response with value.

If you are using chrome then you need to activate the logXMLHTTPREQUEST in console. For activate each request and response you can Right click on console and click on logXMLHTTPREQUEST option.

Comment: Would you give me detail explains of debugging in browser steps by steps ?

Comment: Open Tools menu and click on Developer Tools menu in google chrome. It will open small window in bottom of browser or press SHIFT + CTRL + I for open the debug mode view.

Right Click on debug window and it will open the small with few option, So you can active or click on logXMLHTTPREQUEST option.

After activate logXMLHTTPREUEST option when ever you can do any operation on ODOO then it will display the all http request in console tab of debugger window.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it in linux

Stop your server from running as a daemon
/etc/init.d/openerp stop

Put the python debugger inside the .py file of odoo you want to debug and step through.

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

start your server from the command line as the openerp user
./server/openerp-server --database=DB_NAME

access your program from the browser and it will break when i reaches your python debugger

Answer (score 1):

Open the console (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and then get the broker object to the server model you want to access (in this sample "Leads"):

```
var Leads = new openerp.Model('crm.lead');
```

In openerp v7.0 you can get the broker this way:

```
var instance = openerp.instances.instance0
var Leads = new instance.web.Model('crm.lead')
```

After that make your query, filter the results and specify what you want to do with the object list (in this case count):

```
Leads.query(['id']).all().then(function(leads){console.log(leads.length)})
```

in this case show the Id of the first:

```
Leads.query(['id']).first().then(function(lead){console.log(lead.id)})
```

More samples and docs for odoo:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html#rpc

More samples and docs for openerp:

http://openerp-web-v7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html#rpc

Answer (score 0):

[image: ODOO debugging menu]

You need to Activate the "Assets Debugging" to make the javascript debuggable of the QWEB (assets). You need to enable the debugging mode of odoo firstly to see the debugging button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension in chrome to debug odoo.

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odoo-debug/hmdmhilocobgohohpdpolmibjklfgkbi?hl=en
```